# Issue with allowing specific file extensions

Tags: php, file-upload, file-extension

I'm using simple if else statement to allow specific file type for uploading

```
$file_type = $_FILES["userfile"]["type"];

$allowed = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "application/pdf");

if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)){ } else{ $err .= "not allowed"; return 0; }
```

But it does not work.

Is there any alternate way to allow only specific type of files ?

Comment: It looks like your logic is backwards... Your `$allowed` array is being used as a blacklist.

Comment: I'm with Jasper on this one, you have `if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed))`. This means your if condition won't fire unless the file type is NOT in `$allowed` array. Remove the `!` for starters :D

Comment: @rid What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @rid Thanks for the link, I shall give it a read :)

Comment: ok can u provide another way ??

Answer (score 0):

The PECL Fileinfo extension might be your best best for detecting file types.  Here is link to documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

A usage example:

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
```